# Add blacklist to facebook fb:comment plugin without relating to a app_id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-comments

I want to add a blacklist to my fb:comment plugin, I have it on my website, but facebook docs only show me how to add the blacklist for an app using the [moderation dashboard](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/). **I do not have an app_id, I am just using the plugin**

This does not apply for only using the plugin. This is my code:

```
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
 <fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

I have also the meta-tag:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234567..ect">
```

I know how to add the blacklist when having an app, but when you are using just a plugin how can you add this blacklist, can be something like

```
<fb:comments blacklist="porn"... </fb:comments>
```

??

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards!

Comment: try using default app_id "966242223397117".

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done, you **must** associate to an **app_id** if you want to use the **blacklist**